# Historical airfare prices to understand which month has the lowest airfare

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, money

Is there a service (don't mind paying a bit) that will tell me historically which month has the lowest airfare between two travel destinations? The thing is, that I need to fly to India from Canada (return trip) to see my family every year but I am flexible with time of visit.

So it will be helpful if I could get an idea when the airfare for this route is historically low.

Comment: I think for Canada or at least air Canada flying out of the country/round trips it's cheaper to get tickets in the winter/first quarter of the year for tickets later in the year. Once the good weather starts, I believe the price goes up. My wife always gets our ticket in april or earlier for something that's in sept or october

Comment: Although posted later, your question is answered [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43279/how-can-i-check-when-i-can-statistically-fly-to-given-locations-most-cheaply/43291#43291), so I would like to redirect you to that page instead of copy-pasting here.

Answer (score 2):

I recently found a website showing reports that are interesting from this point of view.

[Hopper](http://www.hopper.com/) shows much information in reports for any pair of origin/destination airports.

For you, I took the example of [Montreal-Mumbai](http://www.hopper.com/flights/from-YUL/to-BOM/guide) (as you did not specify which airports you targeted - I let you read the report for your expected trip). What we can see is it is cheaper in April - but March seems good as well. Apparently it is better to fly out on a Sunday and fly back on a Tuesday.

You can find more information in their full report but that might be too much and anyway it depends on a lot of things, including as @pnuts suggested, on the price of oil which varies a lot.