# What should be my expectations for airfare to France?

Tags: air-travel, france

I live in the US and want to plan a trip to France. It would take place either during a summer or possibly next April. When I search for airfares, what should my expectations be? What counts as a good deal?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. What constitutes a good deal is personal and depends on a huge number of factors— when you book, whether and where you connect, your cabin, your frequent flyer status, your accrual level, your schedule, the airline and its service reputation, and so on. If your overriding concern is price, I would start with Hopper and Kayak as suggested in *[Historical airfare prices to understand which month has the lowest airfare](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/42531)*. Also see [538 article on when to book](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/when-to-hold-out-for-a-lower-airfare/).

Comment: Fair point about the large number of factors. But surely it's a fairly objective question, no? If there's an average price, anything below that is a good deal. My overriding concern is not price, necessarily, but "What should I expect to pay?" seemed like a reasonable question to think about.

Comment: Let me ask you this: is $750 a good price for a round trip flight between New York and Los Angeles? If it's an unrestricted full Y fare, it's a great deal. If it's in international business class, it's a great deal. If it's a middle seat in economy but you bought it an hour before departure, it's a great deal. If there's a special frequent flyer promotion and you get triple EQMs for the flight, it's a great deal. If it's a nonstop from LaGuardia to Burbank and you happen to be traveling from Astoria to North Hollywood, it's worth a thought. But for restricted economy? It stinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your airfare depends on your departure airport, your destination airport, when you travel, when you buy the ticket compared to how many tickets are already sold, whether you go for the cheapest option or spend more with upgrades and some more details.

[Kayak](http://www.kayak.com/flights) shows flights with one stop over from NYC to Paris in April 2016 for $630, direct flights are all above $1000. That might give you something to start with.

But best check the dates you are thinking about and the airports that are suitable for you on a flight search site.

Prices will be higher for the summer, will be higher if you have to cross the USA as well and when more tickets are sold for the planes but not all prices go up at the same speed.

Comment: Hopper gives insights for flights : http://www.hopper.com/flights/from-JFK/to-CDG/guide